# How to force creation of OpenIddict tables in not empty DB

Tags: openiddict

Does anybody know whether there is a way to use default OpenIddict storage functionality in a project which doesn't use Entity Framework and has not empty DB?

I'm trying to integrate Openiddict server to my Web App. The app has a DB, but communication with it is done using classic ADO.Net. I tried to find a similar example in the `openiddict-samples` repository but unfortunately without result.
I know that I can implement my own `TokenStore`, `ApplicationStore` etc. and register them via extensions for `OpenIddictCoreBuilder` but I'd like to use the default implementations in case it's possible to do that with not empty DB and without EF or with EF but for Openiddict functionality only. My DB is quite big and it's not an easy task to migrate it to EF.

I tried to use code from existing examples but those didn't work in my case. What I found out is that it works with empty DB only, otherwise OpenIddict tables are not created.

So I would very appreciate for any advice or link to example which I should investigate more carefully. So to say make OpenIddict to create its tables automatically, under the hood.

P.S.: I of course can copy those tables from examples and include scripts for their creation in my app, but I'd like to use the built-in functionality as much as possible.

OpenIddict version: `3.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for now there is no a built-in functionality to achieve the wanted behavior. The only way is to create own `Stores` and `StoreResolvers` for `OpenIddict` and migrate tables creation to any suitable solution: a set of sql scripts, some kind of migration (e.g. `FluentMigration`), etc.
For now `OpenIddict` out of the box supports EF and Mongo only. This implementations can be considered as examples for implementation of `Stores` and `StoreResolvers`.